# Text between string provided examples below

Tags: ssms

Hi have a string like these in a column:
Abc_def_ghi_contact.pdf
Asdd_dk_hk_can.pdf
The result which i need are
To extract what ever is there
Before the . And after the last _ in the above
Result for above should be
Cantact
Can
Need this in SSMS code

Answer (score 0):

If you have always have .pdf extension file below query works.

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'Abc_def_ghi_contact.pdf'

select 
        SUBSTRING(
            right(@str, charindex('_', reverse(@str) + '_') - 1)
            ,1
            ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',right(@str, charindex('_', reverse(@str) + '_') - 1)) >1 
                        THEN CHARINDEX('.',right(@str, charindex('_', reverse(@str) + '_') - 1))-1
                        ELSE LEN(right(@str, charindex('_', reverse(@str) + '_') - 1))
                        END
            )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but in some case after the . It has tif or some other text so i need the text before the . Not just the pdf

Comment: It giving an error of invalid length parameters passed to left or substring function

Comment: It is happening because of the last -1 if i remove it works but . Comes at the end in result but if i ise -1 it through an error

Comment: @utkarshbharal I have updated the solution to handle when there is no dot(.) in the string